# glGenBuffers vs glGenTextures

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

What exactly is the difference between `glGenBuffers` and `glGenTextures`? I've noticed that both work just fine when I try to generate a texture:

```
int texture1 = GL30.glGenBuffers();
GL30.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture1);

int texture2 = GL30.glGenTextures();
GL30.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture2);
```

Both of these seem to behave exactly the same for me. Is there any advantage to using `glGenTextures` over `glGenBuffers`? And if not, why does `glGenTextures` even exist when `glGenBuffers` can just be used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glGenTextures` and `glGenBuffers` doesn't create any objects or buffers, they just marke object names as used. This means they reserve objects names.
While `glGenTextures` reserves texture names, `glGenBuffers` reserves buffer names, but the names returned by `glGenTextures` may be the same as the names returned by `glGenBuffers`.
`glGenTextures` just guarantees that the names which are returned are not used for the purpose of textures.
`glGenBuffers` guarantees that the names which are returned are not used for the purpose of buffers.

Note, a buffer object and a texture object may have the same value, but there are 2 completely different objects. A name which is returned by `glGenBuffers` is not marked used (or reserved) for the used as a texture object, but it is reserved for use as a buffer object.

[OpenGL ES 3.2 Specification - 8.1 Texture Objects; page 140](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/es_spec_3.2.pdf)

> The command
>
> ```
> void GenTextures( sizei n, uint *textures );
> ```
>
> returns `n` previously unused texture names in textures. These names are **marked as used, for the purposes of `GenTextures` only**, but they acquire texture state and a dimensionality only when they are first bound, just as if they were unused.

[OpenGL ES 3.2 Specification - 6 Buffer Objects; page 50](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/es_spec_3.2.pdf)

> The command
>
> ```
> void GenBuffers( sizei n, uint *buffers );
> ```
>
> returns `n` previously unused buffer object names in buffers. These names are **marked as used, for the purposes of `GenBuffers` only**, but they acquire buffer state only when they are first bound with `BindBuffer` (see below), just as if they were unused.

---

Note, the OpenGL ES specification differs here from the (desktop) OpenGL core profile specification. 
In (desktop) OpenGL core profile, it is not valid to pass a value to `glBindTexture`, which was not return by `glGenTexture`.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification  - 8.1 Texture Objects; page 180](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

> The binding is effected by calling
>
> ```
> void BindTexture( enum target, uint texture );
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> **Errors**
>   [...]
>   An `INVALID_OPERATION` error is generated if texture is not zero or a name returned from a previous call to `GenTextures`, or if such a name has since been deleted.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. So they both return names from different namespaces? Are there any negative consequences of using a buffer name for a texture? And why are there even two namespaces to begin with?

Comment: @PeaBrain According to the specification there are no negative consequences. But who knows how an graphics driver would deal with that and how the performance is affected?

Comment: @Rabbid76: According to the OpenGL ***ES*** specification, perhaps. But the desktop OpenGL specification, core profile, does not allow you to use names that have not been reserved by the system for objects of that type. You get `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` if you try it.